# Help with resizing image in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-ui, resize

[image]

Ok so I'm just trying to resize the div properly and have the image inside it resize as well.

Here is an example of the container and image that are generated dynamically:

```
<div id="imgD' + i + '" style="border:1px solid red;display:inline-block;position:absolute;">
    <img alt="Big" id="imgA' + i + '" width="' + Math.round(resourceData[i][2] * currentScale) + '" height="' + Math.round(resourceData[i][3] * currentScale) + '" src="' + uploadFolder + '/' + imgData[resourceData[i][1]][1] + '" />
</div>
```

Then the image has Jquery resizable added onto it, and the container has the draggable added onto it.  All working fine.  until I try to resize both elements when the client 'zooms in'.

Here is my resize code:

```
        $('#imgD' + i).css("width", (resourceData[i][2]*currentScale));
        $('#imgD' + i).css("height", (resourceData[i][3]*currentScale));

        // Lets try every combination, like a hero!
        $('#imgA' + i).css("width", (resourceData[i][2]*currentScale));
        $('#imgA' + i).css("height", (resourceData[i][3]*currentScale));
        $('#imgA' + i).attr("width", (resourceData[i][2]*currentScale));
        $('#imgA' + i).attr("height", (resourceData[i][3]*currentScale));

        $('#imgD' + i).css("left",(resourceData[i][4]*currentScale) + "px");
        $('#imgD' + i).css("top", (resourceData[i][5]*currentScale) + "px");
```

The resize icon thing bottom right of the image would indicate this is a problem relating to the jquery resizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the answer I'm afraid, but you can optimise your code quite a bit by chaining the methods for an element, like so:

```
     $('#imgD' + i).css({  width: (resourceData[i][2]*currentScale),
                          height: (resourceData[i][3]*currentScale)});
// Lets try every combination, like a hero!
     $('#imgA' + i).css({  width: (resourceData[i][2]*currentScale),
                          height: (resourceData[i][3]*currentScale)})
                   .attr({ width: (resourceData[i][2]*currentScale),
                          height: (resourceData[i][3]*currentScale)});
     $('#imgD' + i).css({   left: (resourceData[i][4]*currentScale) + "px",
                             top: (resourceData[i][5]*currentScale) + "px"});
```

Comment: I'm sure you know that, but others who look at this posting may not.

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery resiable adds a DIV to the image.

```
('#imgA' + i).parent().css("width", (resourceData[i][2]*currentScale));
$('#imgA' + i).parent().css("height", (resourceData[i][3]*currentScale));
$('#imgA' + i).css("width", (resourceData[i][2]*currentScale));
$('#imgA' + i).css("height", (resourceData[i][3]*currentScale));
```

Use the parent selector to resize that div.